# SPARQL to encompass all sub-properties of a property

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want all Wikidata items that have ended, so I wrote this:

```
?item wdt:P582 ?endtime.
```

Problem: it does not include items that have been "abolished".
[abolished](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P576) is a subproperty of [end time](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P582).

**QUESTION**: How to encompass all subproperties?

---

Current query that does not include subproperties:

```
SELECT
    ?item ?endtime
WHERE {
    ?item p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3917681. # Embassies...
    ?item wdt:P582 ?endtime. # ... that have ended
}
```

I could do a UNION with all known sub-properies, but new sub-properties may appear in the future.

Comment: `?p_ wdt:P1647* wd:P582 . ?p_ wikibase:directClaim ?p . ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3917681 . ?item ?p ?endtime .` You could also add `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Wikidata includes subproperty relationships, you just need:

```
?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* wdt:P582 .
?item ?p ?endtime.
```

Comment: Sir, it's a great honour for me to downvote your answer! The nuance is that `wdt:P1647` (which is analogous to `rdfs:subPropertyOf`) connects property items (`wd:P...`), not truthy predicates (`wdt:P...`).

Comment: @stanislavkralin OP's question included `?item wdt:P582 ?endtime.` and didn't specify any prefix declarations. So, is that part of OP's query is correct, then OP would want subproperties of it. Even if there might be web-based query interfaces that predefined certain namespaces, those have been known to change over time. For instance, some of the namespaces that DBpedia's end point used to declare have changed. It's also possible that OP specified a non-standard prefix.

Comment: of course, prefixes are conventional, but the difference between them is not, as well as the difference between property entities and truthy predicates in Wikidata. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Prefixes_used That's why `?p wdt:P1647 wd:P582` does work, while `?p wdt:P1647 wdt:P582` doesn't.  .